# How to block access to YouTube website on a child' smartphone

Tags: youtube, mobile, google-family-link, parental-control

Through Family Link my daughter can't install YouTube app on her phone, but she can access youtube.com using a web browser such as Firefox.

Is there a way in Family Link or through another means to block certain websites independently of which browser app is used to visit them?

Comment: Have you already look for similar questions on [android.se] / [apple.se]? Since Family Link is  mobile app, not a web app, questions about Family Link are off-topic here.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about managing mobile phones.